# Vector not being set correctly

Tags: r

This R code :

```
avector <- as.vector(top.links.added.overall$Amount)
x <- as.vector(top.links.added.overall[order(avector),])
x$Amount <- factor(x$Amount)
x$color[x$Amount == 100] <- "red"
x$color[x$Amount == 500] <- "blue"
x$color[x$Amount == 1000] <- "darkgreen"
dotchart(x$Amount,
         labels = row.names(x),
         cex=.7,
         groups = x$Amount,
         gcolor = "black",
         color = x$color,
         pch=19,
         main = "Gas Mileage for Car Models\ngrouped by cylinder",
         xlab = "Miles Per Gallon")
```

returns this error :

```
Error in dotchart(x$Amount, labels = row.names(x), cex = 0.7, groups = x$Amount,  : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector or matrix
```

This is the datafile for top.links.added.overall :

```
Amount,Name
1000,Google
500,Cnn
100,Yahoo
```

'x' is a vector so what is causing this error ?

Comment: `x` is a factor since you called `x$Amount <- factor(x$Amount)` but should be numeric vector

Comment: @DrDom yes that works, put your comment into an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove conversion to factor `x$Amount <- factor(x$Amount)`
And make small change in

```
dotchart(x$Amount,
     labels = row.names(x),
     cex=.7,
     groups = factor(x$Amount),
     gcolor = "black",
     color = x$color,
     pch=19,
     main = "Gas Mileage for Car Models\ngrouped by cylinder",
     xlab = "Miles Per Gallon")
```

Probably that will help you.

Comment: why are you using 'factor(x$Amount)' instead of x$Amount ?

Comment: From help page: "`groups` - an optional factor indicating how the elements of x are grouped. If x is a matrix, groups will default to the columns of x." So it should be a factor and I made an explicit conversion to factor, but probably `dotchart` can do it automatically.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarification, the result labels are different when I omit it